# PHP - Elegantly extract the numeric indices in array a that are not in array b (not array_diff_key)

Tags: php

Suppose you have two arrays `$a=array('apple','banana','canaple');` and `$b=array('apple');`, how do you (elegantly) extract the numeric indices of elements in array a that aren't in array b? (in this case, indices: 1 and 2).

*In this case, array a will always have more elements than b.*

Note, this is **not** asking for `array_diff_key`, but rather the numeric indices in the array with more elements that don't exist in the array with fewer elements.

Comment: `array_keys(array_diff($a, $b))`?

Comment: @u_mulder Please avoid writing possible answers as comments. If you think that's the solution, post a quick answer with a code sample, and I'll happily upvote it.

Comment: And what's the problem with possible answer in comments?

Comment: @IMSoP I’d rather see this question closed for zero effort, actually …

Comment: @CBroe there was an effort. They obviously figured out that `array_diff` was the right direction.

Comment: @u_mulder Comments can't be voted on, edited, or easily discussed further. Most importantly, the question will stay "unanswered", because the system doesn't know your answer is an answer. If the question should be closed, answering it rewards the asker, whether it's in a comment or a real answer, so that's not a reason to put it there either. Comments are for _clarifications to the question_; your comment doesn't attempt to clarify anything, the only possible response is to say "that's not the right answer", which is what voting and comments on answers are for.

Comment: @CBroe If you want to vote to close, do so, _and do not provide an answer_. Providing an answer, either in the Answer box or the Comment box is the worst things to do with a question you think should be closed, because the user gets what they were looking for, leaves happy, and isn't encouraged to improve this or future questions. In other words: Vote To Close and Answer are mutually exclusive actions, and "Answer, but in the Comment box" doesn't change that.

Answer (score 5):

`array_diff` gets you half way there. Using [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array-keys) on the diff gets you the rest of what you want.

```
$a = ['apple','banana','canaple'];
$b = ['apple'];
$diff = array_diff($a, $b);
$keys = array_keys($diff);

var_dump($keys); // [1, 2]
```

This is because `array_diff` returns both the element and it's key from the first array. If you wanted to write a PHP implementation of `array_diff` it might look something like this...

```
function array_diff(Array ... $arrays) {
    $return = [];

    $cmp = array_shift($arrays);

    foreach ($cmp as $key => $value) {

        foreach($arrays as $array) {

            if (!in_array($value, $array)) {
                $return[$key] = $value;
            }

        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

This gives you an idea how you might achieve the result, but internally php implements this as a sort, because it's much faster than the aforementioned implementation.

Comment: This is not said in the manual __explicitly__ that `array_diff` does not modify keys. So though this is a working solution, once `array_diff` changes to return 0-indexed array, this will cause bugs.

Comment: @u_mulder No it won't.

Comment: You're a php core developer?

Comment: @u_mulder Yes, I am.

Comment: I doubt, but okay.

Comment: @u_mulder - this was the solution you proposed in the comments

Comment: Does this also work when the words in array b varies in order from the words in array a?

Comment: @ina Yes, order does not matter here.